# Retrieval of a page from CRM server failed due to an error

Tags: dynamics-crm, outlook-2010

Accounts and Leads are not loading  in crm outlook.

All other entities are working fine. When i click on accounts and leads an error comes as "Retrieval of a page from CRM server failed due to an error".

These Entities Work fine in Internet Explorer.

I Changed Diagonisitcs settings,reinstalled crm for outlook,synchronized it again but, still the same problem.

How can i over come this problem. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using fiddler to track the web pages that the CRM addon for outlook tries to request when you click on accounts or leads, maybe the URL is wrong.

If you feel that it is the correct URL then try to browse it through IE and check if the problem is in the page itself or in the outlook addon.

Good luck!